# UK Skilled Worker visa after Canada Tourist visa refusal

Tags: united-kingdom, canada

I am an Indian citizen working in Germany for 2 years and I hold a German residence permit. In Dec 2019, I applied for the Canada tourist visa which was refused for not having sufficient funds, family ties in Canada. I am working in a Software Firm and earning 60000 Euros annually.

Now, I want to apply for the UK Skilled Worker visa as I've landed a JOB in London.

Does my Canada Tourist Visa refusal in 2019 affect the UK Work Visa?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised Canada refused your application in any part for lack of funds with a 90k salary. You will have to declare the refusal but in general the assessment for work visa applications does not concern family ties or sufficient funds (provided the job comes with a qualified salary).

Comment: Thanks for the help :) @zhantongz

Comment: Tier-2 visa is an immigration route, you are not required to show a tie-back or proof of funds (if your sponsor is A rated)

Comment: You will not be refused based on a tourist visa refusal but make sure you are declaring that in your UK application.

Comment: Thanks Iman. I've mentioned "visa refused due to not enough funds as I wanted to take a 2 month vacation & travel across Canada"
I have a follow up question. @zhantongz or you can help me if possible.
I've visited London 2 times in past on Business Visitor Visa for my work. But on the Visa vignette when i checked now it says " No work or recourse to public funds".
When I'm asked a question for reason of visit should I select the "Work" checkbox in application form ? I assume Yes just wanted to confirm. Thanks in advance.